# How to open a file in new browser window?

Tags: java, vaadin

I'm simply trying to open an XML file in a new browser window. I am using Vaadin/Java. The XML file lives here:

```
C:\Users\USER\workspaceluna\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\wtpwebapps\EVOLtWeb\WEB-INF\xmlfiles\user.xml
```

This is what I have so far, and all it does is open a blank window:

```
this.details.setTargetName("_blank");
this.details = new ActiveLink("LINK", new ExternalResource(VaadinService.getCurrent().getBaseDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "\\WEB-INF\\xmlfiles\\" + user + ".xml"));
```

Comment: If you inspect the page, does the terminal show any errors related to finding that file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this working using **Vaadin's BrowserWindowOpener**. If you want the page to open in a new browser window you need to define a height and width in setFeatures. To open in a new tab within the current browser, just remove the height and width definitions and add setWindowName("_blank"):

```
    BrowserWindowOpener opener = new BrowserWindowOpener(UI.class);
//  opener.setFeatures("height=700,width=600, resizeable, scrollbars, location=0, status=0, toolbar=0"); //removing this line and setWindowName to _blank opens in new tab
    opener.setResource(new FileResource(new File(VaadinService.getCurrent().getBaseDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/WEB-INF/xmlfiles/" + user + ".xml")));
    opener.setWindowName("_blank");
    opener.extend(details);
```

https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/advanced/advanced-windows.html

Answer (score 0):

Why did you use "user" variable instead of "user" string? It looks like all you need is the "user" string.

Can you print "VaadinService.getCurrent().getBaseDirectory().getAbsolutePath()" with println()?

Comment: The user variable gets created in the same method based on what user generates the file.